# How to solve Inexact First-Order Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have $xy' + y = \log x +1$.$~~~$
I started with $x\,dy + ( -\log x - 1 + y)\,dx = 0$.$~~~$ So $M(x,y) = x$ and $N(x,y) = -\log x - 1 +y$.$~~~$ Then I compute $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = 1$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial y} = -1$. They are not equal, so I continue with $\mu\cdot M(x,y)\,dy + \mu\cdot N(x,y)\,dx = 0$.$~~~$ So $$μ = \frac{N\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} - M\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial y}}.$$

I stack here, please help me, what I need to do now.

Thank you!

Comment: When you multiplied by $\mu$, you didn't change the equation, so you can't establish that it's actually something.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactFirst-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

Comment: (1) Don't delete your comments. It looks like I'm talking to myself. (2) Go to step (17) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, three methods to solve $xy'+y=\ln(x)+1$ :

First : Search for obvious particular solution :

$y=\frac{1}{x}$ is an obvious solution of the homogeneous $xy'+y=0$ and $y=\ln(x)$ is an obvious solution of the ODE. So, the general solution is :
$$y=\frac{c}{x}+\ln(x)$$

Second : Method of variation of parameter :

Solving of the associated homogeneous ODE : $xy'+y=0 \quad\to\quad \frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{dx}{x} \quad\to\quad \ln|y|=-\ln|x|+c \quad\to\quad y=\frac{C}{x}$

Renplacing the parameter $C$ by an unknown function : $\quad y=\frac{f(x)}{x} \quad\to\quad x\left(\frac{f'}{x}-\frac{f}{x} \right)+\frac{f}{x}=\ln(x)+1 \quad\to\quad f'=\ln(x)+1 $
$$f=x\ln(x)+c \quad\to\quad y=\frac{f}{x}=\frac{c}{x}+\ln(x)$$

Third : with integrating factor $\mu$ :

$$(y-\ln(x)-1)dx+xdy=0$$
$$N(x,y)dx+M(x,y)dy=0 \quad \begin{cases} N(x,y)=(y-\ln(x)-1) \\ M(x,y)=x \end{cases}$$
$\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}=1=\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$ Thus $\mu=1$ (case of exact differential).

$$(xdy+ydx)-(\ln(x)+1)dx=d(xy)-d(x\ln(x))=0$$
$$xy-x\ln(x)=c \quad\to\quad y=\frac{c}{x}+\ln(x)$$

Of course, they are other methods, for example Laplace transform.